# Repeated Logistic Regression over time

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, predictive

I have a dataset of people where I know their age, address, and past behaviour. I know the date on which they took a certain action and Im trying to create a logistic regression model to identify who was most likely in to undertake the action on any given day.

What I can do is create a data frame for each day as below. note - Sex remains the same over time, events are a running total of some past behaviour which I think makes the outcome more likely, address may change, outcome is what is being predicted "did this person do the thing I want to predict or not on this day?". The example below is what the data may look like on two different days.

I can create a logistic regression model for each day and add in the probabilities as per below.

However my data has thousands of people and events over several years. What I ultimately want to do is top slice the top 1%, 2% and 3% by probabilities each day and compare the predicted individuals to another predictive model.

The issue is I can't create a data frame for each day and generate a separate model for each day, there are thousands of days. Is there some way of automating this the production of a logistic regression model for each day.

```
day_one_data = data.frame(sex=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
events=c(0, 1, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0),
age=c(21, 18, 40, 18, 19, 35, 22, 39),
address=c(4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 4),
outcome=c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)

model <- glm(outcome~sex+events+age+address, family = "binomial",  data=day_one_data)

day_one_data$outcome_prob <- predict(model, day_one_data, type="response")

day_two_data = data.frame(sex=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0),
events=c(1, 2, 1, 6, 2, 0, 1, 0),
age=c(22, 19, 40, 18, 20, 36, 22, 40),
address=c(4, 1, 2, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3),
outcome=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)
)

model_two <- glm(outcome~sex+events+age+address, family = "binomial",  data=day_two_data)

day_two_data$outcome_prob <- predict(model_two, day_two_data, type="response")
```

As a result of the accepted answer I have added in an example of the structure of my data as to make what I am trying to achieve clearer.

```
#example

full_data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4,2,1,5,6,6,4), # unique ID number - in the real data there are 30K+ individuals

sex = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male"), # gender which is static

event_date = c("2019-09-27 150021043000000585680090","2019-10-01 150021043000000585680090","2019-11-24 150021043000000585680090","2019-12-09 150021043000000585680090","2020-01-01 150021043000000585680090","2020-02-01 150021043000000585680090","2020-03-01 150021043000000585680090","2020-04-10 150021043000000585680090", "2020-05-12 150021043000000585680090","2020-06-12 150021043000000585680090"), # date of the event, this is the outcome I any trying to predict those most likely to do this on any given day, the event is rare the majority of people do not do it at all on that day, there are 60K events some individuals do the event multiple times

age = c(20, 22, 24, 19, 22, 21, 35, 24, 24, 20), # age at time of event

previous_events = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), # count of previous events prior to the one happening on this event_date

address = c("A123", "B123", "C123", "A123", "B123", "A123", "D123", "B123", "B123", "A1234" )) # static postcode which is a zipcode equivalent, covers a large neighbourhood so some people share a postcode)
```

The aim is to have an output of a logistic regression model for each day that shows the likelihood of each individual in the data undertaking an event on that day, as the suggested answer does I would then top slice by percentiles.

Comment: You could include `day` in your model, interacting with as many terms as you want. Or perhaps a hazard model may be more appropriate - it's hard to tell with the details you've provided. I'd suggest posting a similar question on stats.stackexchange.com asking for what modeling approach would be best. If you frame the question in terms of what you want to learn rather than what model you want to fit, you'll probably get better help. (Presumably, fitting models isn't your main goal.)

Comment: thanks @GregorThomas I'll try stats.stackexchange.com - you're correct fitting the model is not the objective. The objective is to have the output of the logistic regression for every person on every day over a period of years, so there will be a output score for each day and 100s in all, rather than the day being an independent variable into the model. The aim would be to identify the most likely people each day to do the thing we are predicting

Comment: Mathematically, fitting a model for each day is equivalent to fitting a big model with a `day` term interacted with every other term. But that's not what I mean by "goal"...

Comment: *"The aim would be to identify the most likely people each day to do the thing we are predicting"* This is getting close to what I mean by "goal". You're saying that you want to estimate, for a given day in your data, which people were the most likely to do this thing. You don't want information about other days to improve those estimate, hence separate models with no sharing of information between them (as opposed to a big model which could allow for sharing some information between days). Does that sound right?

Comment: Further, you only care about days already in your data; you don't want prediction for future days. Nor do you want to make inferences about general characteristics that influence like probability of this thing - building thousands of models will make such inferences more difficult and less powerful.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks again. Let me start again as Im not being clear, Ive started with the code not the problem. Stepping back - I have a dataset that has events by date and time (say buying something or not) and the people involved with demographic data (sex, age etc at time of purchase). I CAN use information from previous days i.e,. previous purchases as an input. What I want to create is a logistic regression prediction for each person on each day on if they will or will not purchase on that particular day. This could lead to targeting the top 0.5, or 1% most likely purchasers per day

Comment: Great, that's much clearer, thank you!

Comment: @GregorThomas this looks like exactly what I needed, thank you. I knew there must be some way to sequence the modelling, I'll give this a go over the next few days, are you any good with hawkes point models ;-)

Comment: Glad to hear it! Never heard of Hawkes point models before.

Comment: They are a self exciting point process, Im trying to compare the logistic regression models to a self exciting point process. The advantage of the later is it bring in social network factors. Its the coding in R which Im struggling with examples for, although there are some things on stack exchange so thanks for that tip too.

Comment: @GregorThomas Ive edited my initial question to show more clearly the structure of my actual data. Your answer I believe is 90% there but my data only has an observation for if the person did do the event on a certain day, not if they didnt. They will appear multiple times as they will do the event several times over the time period. I could add in a negative observation for each person each day? Also I believe your answer is missing one ")" at the end of the code?

Comment: This is complex. You certainly need negative observations, not just positive observations, to build a logistic regression model. Whether every subject should be included every day, and how to handle their covariates will require careful thought and careful coding - and a better understanding of your domain than I can get from short descriptions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: For me, this is crossing the line from a Stack Overflow question to a problem to hire a consultant for. You can follow the link in my profile and reach out over Linked In if you'd like to follow up with me for consulting.

Comment: OK, no problem, I understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fit models in a loop, subsetting the data as needed, and only storing the results that you want to keep - you mention the top 1%, 2%, and 3% for each day.

This code goes through a pre-set vector of dates and fits a model for each date using data from previous days. It then runs a prediction for observations on the date, filters the results down to the top 3%, and puts them in a list.

```
## create a vector of days that you want to model
days = seq(from = as.Date("2021-01-01", to = as.Date("2023-10-16"))

## create a list to store the results
results = list() 

## fit your models and store your predictions
for(i in seq_along(days_to_model)) {
  ## fit the model to earlier data
  day_model = glm(
    outcome ~ sex + events + age + address,
    family = "binomial",
    data = subset(full_data, date < days[i])
  )

  ## predict on the current day
  prediction = subset(full_data, date = days[i])
  predict$pred = predict(
    day_model, 
    newdata = subset(full_data, date == days[i]),
    type = "response")
  )
 
  ## calculate quantiles
  prediction$quantile = cut(
    prediction$pred,
    breaks = quantile(predict$pred, probs = c(0, 0.97, 0.98, 0.99, 1)),
    labels = c("low", "97 %tile", "98 %tile", "99 %tile")
  )

  ## drop all below 97th %tile
  prediction = subset(prediction, quantile != "low")

  ## maybe drop other unneeded columns??

  ## keep the rest
  results[[i]] = prediction  
}

names(results) = days

## access results with, e.g, `results[[40]]` for the 40th day
## or `results[["2022-01-05"]]` for a specific date by name
```